# Cross-talk of condition_variables signal and how to avoid it

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex, conditional-variable

I'm using the mutex and condition_variable pair to implement mult-threaded processing. I have read examples and solid explanations like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32776786/understanding-stdcondition-variables) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61494611/how-to-exit-sleep-when-an-interrupt-arrives). However, I do not understand why separate variables trigger each other. For example,

```
mutex alert0, alert1;
condition_variable var0, var1;
void toy0() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(alert0);
    var0.wait(lock, [=] { return true; });
    cout << "Toy0 triggered" << endl;
}
void toy1() {
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(alert1);
    var1.wait(lock, [=] { return true; });
    cout << "Toy1 triggered" << endl;
}
void main(){
    std::thread t0 = std::thread([=] {
        toy0();
        });
    std::thread t1 = std::thread([=] {
        toy1();
        });

    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(alert0);
        var0.notify_all();
    }
    t0.join();
    t1.join();
    return;
}
```

yields

```
Toy0 triggered
Toy1 triggered
```

If this is the intended outcome, how may I have cross-talk-free signals in different parts of the program so each wait() can be triggered by a specific condition_variable's notify_all(), not others'?

Comment: Condition variables are allowed to wake up spuriously in any case. You need to actually have a condition which you check for in the `wait` predicate.

Comment: @user17732522 Can I conclude that having multiple condition_variable across the program in this case is identical to sharing a single one?

Comment: Whether or not other condition variables are woken up by a notification is up to the implementation. My understanding is that this behavior is to reduce required operating system resources.